# Number of pages in Timber pagination

Tags: wordpress, pagination, twig, timber

I am using version 2 of Timber and I am now adding [pagination](https://timber.github.io/docs/v2/guides/pagination/) to my archives.

Timber, by default, returns 9 pages in the array for pagination. However, I'd rather only want to show first page, the last one and in between the current one with 2 surrounding pages.

The situation as I would like to see it:
For page 1:
`1 | 2 | 3 | ... | 300 | Next >`

For example page 7:
`< Back | 1 | ... | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8| 9 | ... | 300 | Next >`

However the default of Timber (at least for V2) is:
For page 1:
`1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 ... | 300 | Next >`

For page 7:
`< Back | 1 | ... | 4  | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | ... | 300 | Next >`

Because the array with `post.pagination.pages` always contains 9 entries.

I am using the following pagination.twig for that in my templates.

```
{% if posts.pagination.pages is not empty %}
    <nav class="pagination" role="navigation" aria-label="pagination">
        <ol class="pagination__items">
            {% if posts.pagination.prev %}
                <li class="pagination__previous pagination__link">
                    <a href="{{ pagination.prev.link }}">&laquo; {{ __( 'Vorige', 'my-site' ) }}</a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}

            {% for page in posts.pagination.pages %}
                <li class="pagination__link {{ page.class }}">
                    {% if page.link %}
                        <a href="{{ page.link }}">
                            <span class="visually-hidden">{{ __( 'Pagina', 'my-site' ) }}</span> {{ page.title }}
                        </a>
                    {% else %}
                        <span>
                            <span class="visually-hidden">{{ __( 'Pagina', 'my-site' ) }}</span> {{ page.title }}
                        </span>
                    {% endif %}
                </li>
            {% endfor %}

            {% if posts.pagination.next %}
                <li class="pagination__next pagination__link">
                    <a href="{{ pagination.next.link }}">{{ __('Volgende', 'my-site') }}&raquo;</a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
        </ol>
    </nav>
{% endif %}
```

I tried finding a good filter or action to change the settings for this, but unfortunately I can't seem to find one. It looks like version 1 did support this. with `pagination()` though. However I can't find an alternative for this for V2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by [Radek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74385601/8398885) put me on the right trail

```
use Timber\Pagination;

$context['pagination'] = Pagination::get_pagination( [
    'mid_size' => 2,
    'end_size' => 1,
    'show_all' => false,
] );
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs:

https://timber.github.io/docs/v2/reference/timber-pagination/#get_pagination

you could easily pass the arguments here so those are from WordPress docs:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/#parameters

Finally you can use that like this:

```
use Timber\Pagination;

...

$context['pagination'] = Pagination::get_pagination([
    'mid_size' => 1,
    'end_size' => 1,
    'show_all' => false,
]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is deprecated in 2.0 according to the code

https://github.com/timber/timber/blob/2.x/src/Timber.php#L1646

Comment: Ah wait... it's simply been moved.

use Timber\Pagination
Pagination::get_pagination([ ... ]);

Thanks :-)

Comment: Ah sorry, you are right. I posted correct link to docs but code from v1. I have edited the code as well. :-)